# Find the ring of homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show, which well-known ring is isomorphic to ring $End(\mathbf{Z})(+,ͦ,-,0,id)$ of homomorphisms $\mathbf{Z}$ -> $\mathbf{Z}$, where $\mathbf{Z}$ is commutative group $\mathbf{Z}(+)$ and 0 constant zero function.

I struggle with solving this, including the problem of what is considered a "known" ring.

Comment: The entire endomorphism is decided as soon as you choose a target for $1$. Try analyzing $f:1\mapsto 2$. What is $f\circ f$? $f\circ f\circ f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\forall\;m\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;f(m)=f(m\cdot 1)=mf(1)\implies f$$

is completely and uniquely determined by $\;f(1)\;$ , as written in the comments. Now, what image can you choose for $\;f(1)\;$ ? Can you see now what is $\;\text{End}\,(\Bbb Z)\;$ isomorphic to?